# Unable to boot consistently

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I recently bought a HP Pavilion desktop computer, which came with a HDD with Windows 10 in it. I installed a second drive (NVME SSD) where I installed ubuntu MATE 18.04, installing grub in this drive as well. The installation process went apparently fine. Then I entered the BIOS and placed ubuntu as the first entry in the UEFI boot order. So far so good.

Unfortunately, when I turn my computer on, the famous grub minimal bash screen almost always shows up.

To boot correctly to the grub menu, I figured out two ways:

1. Press rapidly F9 to access the UEFI boot selection menu and select ubuntu, which paradoxically is on top of the list.
2. Press F10 to access the BIOS configuration and do nothing, and simply exit without saving changes.

If I'm not quick enough pressing the relevant key, then I type `reboot` and repeat. It usually takes me two or three trials.

I know nothing of the booting sequence but I cannot understand this behavior. How are my workarounds different to simply power my computer on?

---

The output of the following commands is:

- `lsblk`

  ```
  NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
  loop0         7:0    0  71,7M  1 loop /snap/software-boutique/31
  loop1         7:1    0  89,5M  1 loop /snap/core/6130
  loop2         7:2    0  86,9M  1 loop /snap/core/4917
  loop3         7:3    0  86,7M  1 loop /snap/ubuntu-mate-welcome/169
  loop4         7:4    0   7,9M  1 loop /snap/pulsemixer/23
  loop5         7:5    0  87,3M  1 loop /snap/ubuntu-mate-welcome/220
  sda           8:0    0 931,5G  0 disk 
  ├─sda1        8:1    0   260M  0 part /boot/efi
  ├─sda2        8:2    0    16M  0 part 
  ├─sda3        8:3    0 912,5G  0 part 
  ├─sda4        8:4    0   980M  0 part 
  └─sda5        8:5    0  17,8G  0 part 
  sr0          11:0    1  1024M  0 rom  
  nvme0n1     259:0    0 465,8G  0 disk 
  ├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0  14,9G  0 part [SWAP]
  └─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0 450,9G  0 part /
  ```
- `efibootmgr`

  ```
  BootCurrent: 0000
  Timeout: 0 seconds
  BootOrder: 0000,0002
  Boot0000* ubuntu
  Boot0002* Windows Boot Manager
  ```

---

For the record: I managed to boot gracefully by installing rEFInd. The newer versions of ubuntu have it in the official repos. It's a very nice piece of software.

Nevertheless, I'm still curious of what the problem was. I cannot understand this lack of booting consistency.

Comment: please post the output of `lsblk` and `sudo fdisk -l`. I think disk priority is set to wrong disk.

Comment: @Vijay I have posted the output of `lsblk` and `efibootmgr`. The output of `fdisk` is very long and somewhat sensible.

Comment: @Vijay I did that. But I cannot choose disks but UEFI sources in the BIOS of HP. I placed ubuntu on the top of the list.